# Different header and footer for first page and for rest document

Tags: header-footer, titles

I need to define a specific header and footer for the first page and modified header and footer for rest pages. I am familiar with `fancyhdr` package but from my understanding, I can only define not complicated headers and footers the same for all document by commands:

```
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{}
```

I need to provide a template for the first page as follow:
[image]
**And for the rest pages without Logo and Table.**

The problems that I have:

1. How to define different header and footer for the first page and for the rest document.
2. How to create complex footer (table, number below, and page below the number) because when I am using commands `\fancyfoot` and `\cfoot` I got everything in the same line

**EDIT:**
Here is simple code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm,top=15mm,         bottom=20mm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % fancy headers/footers

% Use fancyheadings stuff
\pagestyle{fancyplain}{

% Definition of the header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bf Number}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bf TEXT}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small Title}
\cfoot{\vspace{0pt} \small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Version number}
}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{
% Definition of the header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\bf Number}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{logo}}


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\small number}
\fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{0pt} \small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
\fancyfoot[R]{TEXT}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}
\setcounter{page}{1}
Title page
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\section{The First Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text         text text text text text text text text text text.
\newpage
\section{The Next Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\label{END}
\end{document}
```

Problems:

1. Text on the first page doesn't start after the header.
2. The header and footer for the second and first page are moved more than margins defined in geometry page (the footer is cut).

[image]

[image]

Based on geometry package the footer and header should "start" after margins:
[image]

Comment: For question 1, define a new pagestyle with the command `\fancypagesstyle{mypagestyle}{...}` and use at the relevant place `\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}`. For question 2, please provide a small complete document with what you've tried.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related.

Comment: @Bernard, please look at the edited version.

Comment: @begginer, add the `showframe` option to `geometry` so you can have better idea what is going on margins.

Comment: It should be noted that fancyhdr likes to keep the same size header for the entire document.  Also, \fancypagestyle just changes the fancyhdr options and calls \pagestyle{fancy} again.

Comment: A quick fix would be to \smash the logo.

Answer (score 1):

first change --- icon in header tool large reduce size to 0.1 scale

second change -- vspace in the foote not required since its 0pt and gives white space on top

Now have alook at first page

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % fancy headers/footers

% Use fancyheadings stuff
\pagestyle{fancyplain}{

% Definition of the header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bf Number}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bf TEXT}
%
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt}
%\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small Title}
%\cfoot{\vspace{0pt} \small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
%\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Version number}
%}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{
% Definition of the header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\bf Number}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\small number}
\fancyfoot[C]{ \small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
\fancyfoot[R]{TEXT}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}
\setcounter{page}{1}
Title page
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\section{The First Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text         text text text text text text text text text text.
\newpage
\section{The Next Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\label{END}
\end{document}
```

**For the second page**

Redefine pagestyle as mypagestylea rather than interfere with pagestyle fancy which is the default

now have alook at second page

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % fancy headers/footers

% Use fancyheadings stuff
%\pagestyle{fancyplain}{

% Definition of the header
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
%\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bf Number}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bf TEXT}
%
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt}
%\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small Title}
%\cfoot{\vspace{0pt} \small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
%\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Version number}
%}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{
% Definition of the header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\bf Number}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

%defn of footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\small number}
\fancyfoot[C]{ \small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
\fancyfoot[R]{TEXT}
}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestylea}{
    % Definition of the header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
    \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bf Number}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bf TEXT}
    %
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt}
    \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\small Title}
    \cfoot{\small\bf Page \thepage\ of \pageref{END}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Version number}
    }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}
\setcounter{page}{1}
Title page
\newpage
\pagestyle{mypagestylea}
\section{The First Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text         text text text text text text text text text text.
\newpage
\section{The Next Section}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\label{END}
\end{document}
```

[image]